Correlating series with different sampling frequencies
Intuitively, correlation between x(t) and y(t) seems to assume that x(t) and y(t) have the same sampling frequency.
What if, say, x(t) has sample frequency T, and y(t) has sample frequency T'?
Should we interpolate, downsample or is there some correlation variant which can take into account different sampling frequencies?

A simple starting point would be to aggregate the higher frequency data to lower frequency. The type of aggregation will depend on the measurement of the data.
For example, if x(t) are total quarterly sales of product X and y(t) are total monthly sales of product Y, you could aggregate y(t) to the quarterly frequency by summing sales from each month in the quarter.
Suppose instead that x(t) are sales on the last day of the quarter, and y(t) are sales on the last day of the month. Then, to convert y(t) to quarterly, you would simply use the value from the last month in each quarter.
For more sophisticated methods, a good starting place may be MIDAS regression or Kalman filter methods. However, these are usually used in the context of a regression model, so the main output wouldn't be a Pearson correlation coefficient.
